# Can swagger use predefined java enums during code gen

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using Swagger to generate the client code my APIs. One of the endpoint's input uses a enum. So I had to define the enum as part of YAML definition file, after which Swagger generates the enum java file. But I already have a java enum in the persistence layer. For Example:

This is the swagger definition:
/api/entity/
- entityType
--type1
--type2

But i already have a java enum defined and used on the server side called MyEntityType. Is it possible to mention this java enum in swagger, so that it wont generate the enum again but use the predefined java enum?